# How can I get a consistent answer with operations of piecewise functions?

Tags: signal-processing, graph

I am trying to multiply two signals mathematically and graphically. I have inconsistent answers, I'd appreciate anyone that can show me where I went wrong.

I have two functions of time based on two different signals represented graphically,
$$x(t)= \cases{-1-t&, -1 $\le$ t $\le$ 0 \cr
t&, 0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1 \cr
1&, 1 $\le$ t $\le$ 2 \cr
3-t&, 2 $\le$ t $\le$ 3 \cr
0&, otherwise}$$
$$y(t)= \cases{1&, -2 $\le$ t $\le$ -1 \cr
-1&, -1 $\le$ t $\le$ 0 \cr
-1+t&, 0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1 \cr
1&, 1 $\le$ t $\le$ 2 \cr
0&, otherwise}$$

I was tasked to sketch a graph of
$$f(t)=x(t)y(2-t)$$

If am not mistaken the first step is to evaluate $$y(2-t)$$ by substituting (2-t) for t.
This will yield,
$$y(2-t)= \cases{1&, 4 $\ge$ t $\ge$ 3 \cr
-1&, 3 $\ge$ t $\ge$ 2 \cr
1-t&, 2 $\ge$ t $\ge$ 1 \cr
1&, 1 $\ge$ t $\ge$ 0 \cr
0&, otherwise}$$
Now evaluating f(t),
$$\therefore f(t)= \cases{t&, 0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1 \cr
1-t&, 1 $\le$ t $\le$ 2 \cr
-3+t&, 2 $\le$ t $\le$ 3 \cr
0&, otherwise}$$

My answer was supported by desmos graphing calculator however the text book shows, this graph:
[image: Text book solution]

Comment: Evaluate y(2-t) by substituting t-2 makes no sense.  Subtraction isn't commutative.

Comment: It was a writing mistake, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the book has the wrong waveform...y(2-t) gets inverted along the t axis as shown, but shifts to the right by two instead of the left.  The graph you imported from the book shows y(-2-t).

If you shift y(2-t) right by four from the book graphic, you'll get the same result you derived.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the textbook \$y(2-t)\$ graph is inverted.
These are the graphs generated with MATLAB

```
t = linspace(-2, 4, 2000);
x = @(t) (-1 <= t & t <= 0) .* (-1-t) + (0 <= t & t <= 1) .* (t) + (1 <= t &    t <= 2) .* 1 + (2 <= t & t <= 3) .*(3-t) + 0;

y = @(t) (-2 <= t & t <= -1) .* 1 + (-1 <= t & t <= 0) .* (-1) + (0 <= t & t <= 1) .* (-1+t) + (1 <= t & t <= 2) .* 1 + 0;

shifted_y = @(t)y(2-t);

f = x(t).*shifted_y(t);

subplot(4,1,1)
plot(t,x(t));
title('x(t) Plot');xlabel('t'); ylabel('x(t)');grid
subplot(4,1,2)
plot(t, y(t));
title('y(t) Plot');xlabel('t'); ylabel('y(t)'); grid
subplot(4,1,3)
plot(t, shifted_y(t))
title('y(2-t) Plot'); xlabel('t'); ylabel('y(2-t)'); grid
subplot(4,1,4)
plot(t, f)
title('x(t)y(2-t) Plot'); xlabel('t'); ylabel('x(t)y(2-t)'); grid
```

[image]

And your result is correct.